# Regex match position

Tags: php, regex

```
$str1 = '10 sold';

$re = "/(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)/";       
preg_match_all($re, $str1, $str1matches);

echo print_r($str1matches,1);
```

prints:

```
Array

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 
            [2] => sold
            [3] => 
        )

    [Alpha] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => sold
            [3] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => sold
            [3] => 
        )

    [Numeric] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
        )

)
```

But why does it print such a long array, and how do I determine at which position will my values (`xxx` and `label`) be available always?

Comment: *But why does it print such a long array* Do you mean the empty matches or the subArrays?

Comment: @Rizier123 the empty matches

Comment: can you elaborate this *at which position will my values (xxx and label) be available always?* ?

Comment: `$str1matches['Alpha']` and `$str1matches['Numeric']` look like good candidates

Comment: It is because of the star and the possible backtracking - this allows multiple matches to be true - use `+` and word boundaries to eliminate most of them.

Comment: 1. Fix your regex (so it actually matches the input string).  2. Don't use `preg_match_all` (there should be only one match).

Comment: @3zzy: Please explain the rules: what kind of texts do you intend to match?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the string contains a number and a text eg. `10 sold` or `2 watching` so I'm looking to split then and store separately.

Comment: So, a string can only contain an integer number and one word, like `1 a` or `b 2`, right? Then, you should also use anchors `^` and `$`. Do you really need the named captures? If you use named captures, the whole resulting array will contain both numbered *and* named captures.

Comment: Try just [`preg_match('/^([0-9]+)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)$/', '10 sold', $str1matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);`](https://ideone.com/FYWytm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a simple `/^([0-9]+)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)$/` regex since [you confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319957/regex-match-position?noredirect=1#comment65985484_39319957) there is a number and then a word in the input string:

```
preg_match('/^([0-9]+)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)$/', '10 sold', $str1matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/FYWytm):

```
$str1 = '10 sold';
$re = "/^([0-9]+)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)$/";       
preg_match($re, $str1, $str1matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo print_r($str1matches[1]);
echo print_r($str1matches[2]);
```

The `$str1matches[1]` will contain an array with the Group 1 (number) value and its position, and the `$str1matches[2]` will contain an array with the Group 2 (word) value and its position.